# Error during usage of searchFacebook function in R

Tags: r, facebook-graph-api, rstudio

I am R and Stackoverflow newbie. I have been trying to extract public posts from facebook. I have accesed token from [Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)

I have used the following code.

```
 posts <- searchFacebook(string = "#MichealJackson", token = "XXXXXXXXXXXX", n = 200, since = "27 August 2014 00:00", until = "04 September 2014 00:00")
```

I have been facing an error something like this

```
Error in fromJSON(rawToChar(url.data$content)) : unexpected character '<'
```

I couldn't figure out what the problem is. I will be very much thankful if I can get any help. Thanks in Advance.

Update: I have reinstalled the package from github

```
library("devtools")
install_github("Rfacebook", "pablobarbera", subdir="Rfacebook")
```

It worked absolutely fine. But there is still problem with `getUsers()`. Thanks

Comment: So the only code you are running is `searchFacebook()` but you get that error? Are you sure your versions of `Rfacebook` and `httr` are up to date?

Comment: yes, `Rfacebook` and `httr` are up to date. I checked them before starting my project

Comment: Does this happen with any search? Have you tried the samples in the `?searchFacebook` help page and do they give the same error? Since i'm guessing it's not trivial to get an access token it makes this problem very difficult to reproduce. Seeing the message "unexpected character '<'" makes me wonder if it's returning XML rather than JSON.

Comment: Yeah, I have checked with help. I also found the issue ([Error in fromJSON(rawToChar(url.data$content))](https://github.com/pablobarbera/Rfacebook/issues/7)) on github. I have installed the package again from github. Now I am able to extract the data.